# Position of tags when reading questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

It happens to me rather often that I look at a question such as "How to do whatever with Collections" and while that's what I'm looking for in Java, it's useless if the question refers to, for instance, C#.

So, this is purely a UI thing: how about putting the tags right under the question title, rather than arbitrarily far under the question text itself?

EDIT: here's what I mean

> [image]

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't vote for a UI redesign for just that.. I think tag's are in correct place, and if someone read the question fully, no way he would miss the tag..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra But that's the thing, once you've read the question fully, you understand that it wasn't related to the topic you wanted. Tags are precisely meant to let you quickly discriminate interesting from unrelated content

Comment: @Miquel - I don't open the question without reading tags. If have opened, first I read the title then tags and then the body of the question.

Comment: @hims056 true for the front page, but not so for example, when you look at the related questions on the side bar in this very same page

Comment: @Miquel - Read the second sentence. Just open the question and read tags before the body. :)

Comment: @hims056 :) User Experience is not your thing uh? :D

Comment: I had the same suggestion in mind as OP, but found this question. The only answer claims that tags are displayed on the right-hand margin, but I see none -- perhaps they were taken away in the past 2 years?  (I thought first this might be due to AdBlock, but I disabled it and reloaded questions on two different StackOverflow sites; still no tags displayed on the right.) I support the idea of moving the tags directly under the title.

Comment: Martijn Pieters just informed me, in reply to my comment under the only answer, that tags on the right-hand side were indeed removed recently, making Miquel's suggestion even more relevant. Any chance this could be reconsidered by whoever decides these things?

Comment: @TeemuLeisti: this is a per-site design issue, I'd say. See [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200) for the recent design update, where feedback is being requested.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: on the contrary, the placement of tags in questions is common to all StackOverflow sites, based on a random sample of a few. It doesn't matter for short questions, but the tags are hidden when a longer one is opened. Also, posters often seem to consider the tags as a part of the introduction to the question, so won't repeat the problem area in the question itself. Granted, this is not a huge problem, but still, Miquel's suggestion would make for an improvement in usability.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti: I was assuming that the tags were dropped with the new design for SO, but a troll through the Internet Archive shows the feature was dropped independently some time in the first quarter of 2014, or December 2013 at the earliest.

Answer (score 7):

I fully second this feature request.

In scientific journals the keywords and the classification is also given right at the beginning (below the title or below the abstract) and not at the end of the article.

Answer (score 6):

As the layout apparently changed again over the years, this feature request becomes valid again.

Answer (score 5):

Back in 2012 (when this question was posted on what was then meta.stackoverflow.com), tags were not only listed at the end of the question, but *also* on the right-hand side:

[image: tags]

Unfortunately, sometime on the 28th of February 2014 (just before the big Meta.SO / Meta.SE split) that section was dropped, based on bisecting on The Internet Archive copies of posts.

Comment: Oh. You're absolutely right. And yet I had never even noticed that :S Oh, the misteries of UI design. Or am I the only one that's half blind? ;)

Comment: @Miquel It happens to most of us: [Is a website sidebar a user blind spot?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20364/is-a-website-sidebar-a-user-blind-spot)

Comment: I don't see tags on the right-hand side. Perhaps they were taken away within the past two years?

Comment: @TeemuLeisti: the design was updated *very recently* and that indeed removed the tags from the sidebar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. See my comments on the question, above.

Comment: not any more on the right-hand side

Comment: @fedorquisaysReinstateMonica: nope, things have changed in the intervening close-to-7 years since I posted this. Glad this site isn't going stale!

Comment: Totally agreed :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created an userscript for this request, please find in StackApps. If the tags position is not less than the current window's height, then it will clone and paste the tags list below the post title.

[Clone the tags in questions page, if the tags are not visible in the initial window](https://stackapps.com/q/7445/37357)

For example, after installed the userscript, the output of this post is:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: You have a small screen

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why this hasn't been done yet — for me, tags provide context that's sometimes vital to fully understand a question!

Some comments here seem to be relevant only to particular StackExchange sites — but I've hit this problem on a number of different SE sites.  It's confusing to read a technical question only to find that it's not about the language/platform/system you assumed — but it's equally frustrating to read a movie-related question only to find that it's not about the movie/franchise it first seemed; and similarly when a political or legal question isn't about the jurisdiction you thought.

Yes, you can read the title, scroll/look down to read the tags, and then only scroll/look back up to read the question every time — but that's a hassle, especially as the position is so unpredictable due to the wide variation in question length.  (Some have only a few lines, while many are much longer, especially if they have photos/screenshots.)

A quick check of the last 40 or so questions I've read suggests that in my case about 1/3 are long enough that the tags aren't initially visible, requiring the window to be scrolled to see them.  But of course that will depend a lot on your screen size and resolution, preferred font size, and browser window size (as not everyone reads full-screen), as well as which sites you read and their specific styling and whether you're logged in to them.  And of course things are far worse on a phone screen!

The most obvious place to show tags is under the question; they could go above or below the ‘Asked/Modified/Viewed’ stats.  But they could equally make sense *above* the question.  (I think the right-hand side, where they used to go, would make less sense as it's less-closely associated with the question.  But that would still be an improvement.)  The most important thing is that they're clearly visible in a consistent position, however long the question.

TBH, I'm surprised more people haven't complained about this…